# Picture Gallery Slow & Won't Refresh on HTC G2 w Android 2.3 Gingerbread

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, external-sd, performance, images

I'm having a problem with Picture Gallery not refreshing and loading too slowly on Android 2.3.4 Gingerbread (HTC G2). After I take a picture and then go to add it on foursquare or facebook from picture gallery, the last couple pictures taken aren't there.  Sometimes the last 20 pictures taken aren't there or an entire directory of pictures isn't showing up. A lot of times it takes a long time to load the picture thumbnails and directories.

Is there a way to refresh or fix the Picture Gallery or is there a better 3rd party picture gallery that you can recommend?

Should I reformat or replace my micro SD card to make it work faster?

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like the contents of your SD Card have not been scanned since taking the photos.  Try the [SDrescan](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.bero.sdrescan) app from Market.  This should help in such situations.

Alternatively, you can manually un-mount the SD Card (via `Menu -> Settings -> Storage -> Unmount SD Card`) and re-mount it again.  This should trigger the media scanner to refresh the card's contents.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! How do I make sure my SD Card isn't starting to go?

Answer (score 2):

Use [Quickpic](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.alensw.PicFolder). Its much better than the stock android gallery app both in Gingerbread and ICS

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I downloaded the Fish Bowl Photo Gallery but its got an annoying nag screen that stays on there for 2-3 seconds on each load so I'll try QuickPic  :)

Answer (score 0):

I get the same issue with my G2, so I doubt this is a bad SD card.

Another way to force a rescan is to delete the thumbnail folder. I'll use an app like Astro, and navigate to /mnt/sdcard/DCIM. Delete the .thumbnails folder there and the next time you open the Picture Gallery, it will regenerate the thumbnails, including the missing pictures. That said, I think I'll give SDrescan a try next time this happens to me.