# No files accessible after upgrade to CM10

Tags: cyanogenmod, 4.1-jelly-bean, file-system

I understand that Cyanogenmod 10 is still in early access, but I installed a cm-10-20120910-NIGHTLY-i9100 build to my Samsung Galaxy S 2 anyways. I had a stock 4.0.4 before. I heard that this problem happened with previous CM versions, but couldn't find a fix.

Now, all my files are still on the internal SD card, but built-in apps like Play Music or Gallery can't see them. I can still access these files with PowerAmp or Root File Explorer. Even if I take a picture with the camera, it puts the file in DCIM\Camera where all the other pictures are, but it can only see the picture that I just took. There's no difference in file permission or owners between the files, all of them belong to `system` and group is `sdcard_rw`.

If I connect the device in USB storage mode, I can access all the files from my computer. In MTP mode, I can only see new files.

I tried to `chmod 777` all files; it didn't work.

Does anyone know what I should do? Is there a way to tell android to see my files?

Comment: Run Media Scanner..

Comment: Exact duplicate of http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/29518/cant-access-my-old-files-after-switching-rom-from-aokp-to-cm-even-though-they

Answer (score 1):

Happy to help. Here's a [link](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/26910/17688) to a solution that worked. Notable is the fact that this works for at least two devices that I have troubleshooted, so there's a high probability that this will work for you. While I didn't have the liberty of connecting my device (*a Galaxy Nexus GSM*) in the USB mode, I did see all my files in the MTP mode after doing everything exactly as it is detailed. All the best!