# Problem related to pictures not displayed in gallery

Tags: gallery, images

In mi note prime pictures downloaded from any media like whatsapp are not displayed in gallery but are present in system and are shown in file explorer

Comment: If update for gallery app is available, then update it.
Else go to > setting > apps > gallery app and clear the data and cache.
And then open the gallery app.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make older images in my /sdcard/DCIM folder show up in Gallery?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/25676/how-do-i-make-older-images-in-my-sdcard-dcim-folder-show-up-in-gallery)

Answer (score 0):

The answer cannot be absolutely foolproof, but, since you mentioned media files downloaded from **WhatsApp** as your example, I'll tailor my answer against that specific issue.

Now, there does exist a file whose behaviour is to act as a flag. Whenever said file is put into a folder containing media files, such media won't be indexed by a gallery-type of app.

This flag's name is **.nomedia**, and, as the period at the beginning of its name implies, it's also invisible by default. It can, logically, be created even from an app, it consists of a mere blank file, and its simple deletion (as tested by myself on a CyanogenMod 12.1) **won't** make the stock Gallery display the media previously hidden by it flawlessly (in my case, I needed to reflash the whole firmware).

There does exist a gallery that is able to ignore a **.nomedia** file, though: its name is **QuickPic** (and my intent is not to advertise, but to explain a way of resolving the issue that avoids a complete reflash: wiping the stock Gallery's data *won't suffice*), and, if you search in its settings, you'll be able to display every single folder containing media files, even those potentially unwanted, such as profile photos and avatars.

**Summary: if your gallery does not display a media you know to exist, use a file manager to check if a .nomedia file exists in the same location. If it does, and you wish to view such media, either reflash your firmware (hard way), or try another gallery app (soft way).**